# Tool in QGIS to identify overlapping features?

Tags: aggregate, gis, overlap, qgis

I need to find a way to count overlaying features where 3 or more points appear, I have tried to use the aggregate tool but it just repeats my original layer, have also tried join by location which was unsuccessful

[image]

e.g. 3 or more points on a road that need tp be identified, form into one point where it says count(3)

Comment: I think you are off-topic. Your question is not about programming. We have a sister site about GIS (see links on top right icon). But possibly it is already in tutorial of QGIS

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try 'Select Features by Expression'. You can select your point field and then use a variety of different expressions to get what you're looking for. There is more options under aggregates than the aggregate tool provides or you can select points within a certain distance of one another.
https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/working_with_attributes.html